# Java SWT InterruptedException

Tags: java, swt

I'm new to java but want to learn and not be spoon-fed so please keep that in mind :)

I'm working with swing to make a GUI for sending mass messages using a Java API for Skype. I've figured out my methods and have working code for the mass messenger and all and now i'm with swing. I've made a few buttons and worked out the front end of the GUI now I need to implement my method.

Here is my code so far:

```
private void createContents()
  throws SkypeException, InterruptedException {
    final Mass objCL = new Mass();
    objCL.skype();
    shell = new Shell();
    shell.setSize(450, 300);
    shell.setText("Test");

    text = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    text.setToolTipText("Your message to send");
    text.setBounds(121, 166, 249, 38);

    Button btnSend = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
    btnSend.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                objCL.skype();
              }
    });
    btnSend.setBounds(203, 210, 83, 29);
    btnSend.setText("SEND");

    Link link = new Link(shell, SWT.NONE);
    link.setBounds(10, 250, 83, 15);
    link.setText("<a>Our Website</a>");
}
```

(Code tag left out a '}' Don't worry it is not the problem)

Now the error I have is swing will not allow me to put a

```
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) *InterruptedException* {
                objCL.skype();
              }
```

Eclipse outputs the error as

> Unhandled exception type InterruptedException

Any ideas guys?

Comment: FYI: You don't seem to be using Swing, you seem to using SWT

Comment: Java does not allow you to change the declarations of interface methods like `widgetSelected` to add 'throws'. You must deal with the exception in the method.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap `objCL.skype();` in `try-catch` clause, it is not handled by the outer methods as they have no contextual relationship to each other (the `createContents` method would have been called, exited and the program moved on a long time before `widgetSelected` is called)...

```
try {
    objCL.skype();
} catch (InterruptedException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

See the section on [Catching and Handling Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html) for more details